# Visual overview of your CPanel domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, website

I have so many domains, websites, redirects, DNS entries, etc. in my CPanel. Is there a way to get a visual overview of all my settings? I am just wondering in case I have to rebuild my setup on another machine and also to spot any configuration mistakes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such option available in cPanel/WHM to show the whole server summary all together in one place as in your question. However, for rebuilding the same setup in a different server, you just need to create the full domain backup of each domain from cPanel of the domain or via command line and then restore the same in the new server. The cPanel full backup will include all the necessary data associated with each domain.